# S3 "Invalid according to Policy: Policy expired"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I just recently started getting this error when trying to upload images locally. I didn't used to get the error though. Nothing has changed from the S3 side, or the code side. The upload does still work in production though. I've tried all the usual, restart server, restart computer, change to a different browser, clear cache/cookies, change the expiration in the policy, check my ENV variables exist and are proper....

Here's my coffescript using jQuery Fileupload

```
$("input.fileupload").fileupload
  url: '<%= s3_bucket_url %>'
  type: 'POST'
  autoUpload: true
  dataType: 'xml'
  paramName: 'file'
  acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(jpg|png)$/i
  formData:
    key: '<%= "tmp-uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}" %>'
    AWSAccessKeyId: '<%= Settings.fog.aws_access_key_id %>'
    acl: 'public-read'
    policy: '<%= s3_policy %>'
    signature: '<%= s3_signature %>'
    success_action_status: '201'
  success: (data)->
    # success stuff
  fail: (e, data)->
    # fail stuff
```

Here is my S3 helper

```
module S3Helper

  def s3_bucket_url
    "https://#{Settings.fog.directory}.s3.amazonaws.com"
  end

  def s3_signature
    Base64.encode64(
      OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(
        OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'), 
        Settings.fog.aws_secret_access_key,
        s3_policy
      )
    ).gsub(/\n/, '')
  end

  def s3_policy
    Base64.encode64(
      {
        expiration: 24.hours.from_now.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'),
        conditions: [
          { bucket: Settings.fog.directory },
          { acl: 'public-read' },
          ['starts-with', '$key', 'tmp-uploads/'],
          { success_action_status: '201' }
        ]
      }.to_json
    ).gsub(/\n|\r/, '')
  end
end
```

I'm running out of ideas. Do I need to add the 'Content-Type'? Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: I still don't know why this was happening, but I guess S3 likes Halloween. This just started working again today... 0 code changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is as you say and nothing has changed with your code my guess would be:

> ### [Why do some of my requests randomly fail with a 403 Forbidden?](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1109?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1#04)
>
> Check the system clock and time zone settings on the offending
>   machine. Amazon S3 requires all machines making requests be within 15
>   minutes of an Amazon S3 webserver's clock. Setting up your machines to
>   sync their times with an NTP server in addition to making sure they
>   are patched for the recent Day Light Savings changes should resolve
>   this issue.
>
> This is a common error when a developer decides to deploy their
>   application to another machine.
>
> The response from Amazon S3 will contain the following:
>
> - HTTP Status Code: 403 Forbidden
> - Error Code: RequestTimeToo-Skewed
> - Description: The difference between the request time and the server's    time is too large.

You have to set the timezone correctly, you cannot simply adjust the clock an hour up or down.

Comment: Yeah, I had came across that as well. My clock hasn't changed. DST doesn't hit for a few weeks. I checked to make sure my system clock was synced fully, and OSX checks automatically. The Error Code I get back from amazon isn't "RequestTimeToo-Skewed". I get "AccessDenied" as my error code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused due to "time drift", meaning that the server and client need to be synced time wise. If either drifts too much, you will see Policy expired errors.

Re: the server, be aware that if you are developing locally these days then it is likely that your server is running within some kind of virtual machine, whether that be a VM managed by Vagrant, or perhaps docker-machine. That means that the server in this instance is the guest VM and the time needs to be correct inside that and the time on the host itself is irrelevant.

If you are using docker-machine, you can get inside your instances by doing:

`docker-machine ssh name-of-machine`

and then (assuming *nix):

`date` to check the date & 
`sudo ntpd -q -p pool.ntp.org` to update it.

Comment: Invalid According to Policy: Policy Expired
These errors are most often the result of the system clock on the uploader’s computer  Verify that the time on the computer is correct and attempt the upload again.